# Declare delphi structure with ctypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, delphi, ctypes

I have delphi dll named lib.so
It have structure:

```
TRec1 = packed record
    Version:UInt32
end;
Prec=^TRec1

function get_version(ARec: PRec): integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
  FillChar(ARec, SizeOf(TRec1), 0);
  ARec^.Version := 2;
  Result := 0;
end;
```

Dll have function get_version, that take pointer on this structure and return change structure.

Python code:

```
from ctypes import *
class TRec1(Structure):

_pack_ = 1
_fields_=[
('Version',c_uint32) 
]

PRec1=TRec1()
a=cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/Test_In_memmory_perfomance/lib.so')
print a.get_version(PRec1)
```

Function return Exception,that structure dont declare.
When I try call get_version('string') it return OK, but i dont have callback.

Is my structure declare correctly?

Comment: How is get_version defined in your DLL? That should tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I added difinition of get_version in first post.

Comment: I am not familiar with python, sorry. I would imagine, though, that you need to import PRec and a definition of get_version, and that either your definition of get_version is modified to be a var, or you need to pass the address of PRec1 rather than the instance. I could be wrong - this is just based on my knowledge of Delphi DLLs.

Comment: I don't see any calling convention defined...

Comment: Are you sure this is Delphi rather than FPC?

Comment: Use `FillChar(ARec^, SizeOf(TRec1), 0);` (note the `^` after `ARec`). Your code overwrites the pointer (with nil) and perhaps some subsequent bytes on the stack. But you want to zero out the record, not the pointer.

Answer (score -1):

In my situation this code resolve problem:

```
print a.get_version(byref(PRec1))
```

Can anyone tell me why it work?)

Comment: Well, the Pascal code expects a pointer, and that's what `byref` does. There are a lot of issues with your code though, and I can't really face tackling them all, sorry.

Comment: This is what I meant in my comment that you need to pass the address of PRec1 rather than the instance.

Comment: Such code has worked with another Pascal lib where was need pointer. It was surprise for me. Thanks all.